# Backbone Collection Not Fetching w/ ServiceStack

Tags: backbone.js, servicestack

Alright, so here is my main backbone code

```
(function ($) {
var Job = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var JobList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Job,
    url: "/api/jobs?format=json"
});

var JobView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#jobs'),

    _templatesrc: $("#job-template").html(),
    _template: {},

    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        //create the template
        this._template = Handlebars.compile(this._templatesrc);

        //setup data
        this.collection = new JobList();
        //response function from server query
        var response = function () {
            console.log(arguments);
            self.render();
        };
        var response2 = function () {
            console.error(arguments);
            self.render();
        };
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log("models", this.collection.models);
        $(this.el).html(this._template(this.collection.models));
    }

});
var view = new JobView();
})(jQuery);
```

When i do `this.collection.fetch()` i get nothing. When i do `this.collection.fetch({ success:response, error:response2});` the following error is thrown:

```
Backbone.View.extend.initialize.response2 app.js:29
g.wrapError backbone-min.js:104
f.Callbacks.o jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

In chrome i can tell that it returns a JSON response though, which looks like

```
[{"Client":"hi",
  "ReporterTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
  "TimeTaken":PT0S,
  "Status":"Start"}]
```

Any ideas on why Backbone isn't turning my JSON response into the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken PT0S is not valid JSON. Try to return it wrapped in quotes:

```
[{"Client":"hi",
  "ReporterTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
  "TimeTaken":"PT0S",
  "Status":"Start"}]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to add a bug for this on ServiceStack's github.

Answer (score 0):

I've just [fixed support for TimeSpans](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/52cb0b432e57897f65943f59adad1abbb5d9c26a) in [ServiceStack.Text's JsonSerializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text).

Will be available from v3.94+ on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text) or [GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/downloads).

Comment: Thank you! ServiceStack is amazing, btw